# short version of for-loop with division by zero

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

To get straight to problem, I have following data.

```
A = [170,170,150]
b = 160
C = [2,2]
xb = [b/(k-1) for k in C]
print(xb)
```

**Output:**

```
[160.0, 160.0]
```

Now change C list:

```
A = [170,170,150]
b = 160
C = [2,1]
xb = [b/(k-1) for k in C]
print(xb)
```

**Output:**

```
Error ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Okay expected not run, now we find a solution to run it.

```
xb = []
for k in C:
    try:
        xb.append(b/(k-1))
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        xb.append(0)
print(xb)
```

**Output:**

```
[160.0, 0]
```

My question is how could I write a shorter version of above solution such as first solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for the divide-by-zero case inside the list comprehension, like so:

```
A = [170,170,150]
b = 160
C = [2,1]
xb = [b/(k-1) if k != 1 else 0 for k in C]
print(xb)
```

Output:

```
[160.0, 0]
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I want!

Answer (score 1):

solution on  your one of examples

```
A = [170,170,150]
b = 160
C = [2,1]
xb = [b/(k-1) if k!=1 else 0 for k in C]
print(xb)
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I want!

Answer (score 1):

```
A = [170,170,150]
b = 160
C = [2,1]
xb = [b/(k-1) if k != 1 else 0 for k in C]
print(xb)
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I want!